# Fortify Mass Assignment Because of From URI

Tags: c#, data-binding, fortify

After scanning my code I get Fortify: Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration.

This comes from a controller that uses FromUri:

```
public ReturnType Search([FromUri] SearchType searchObject)
```

I understand that the issue is auto-assigning can cause security problem. But I don't think there is anything to worry about here. Is there a way to fix the fortify issue **without** ignoring or suppressing it? I want to read the query from the URI.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015040/hp-fortify-mass-assignment